# How to implement Gmail Smart-Compose feature in my project using Gmail API?

Tags: autocomplete, gmail-api, gmail-addons

I wanted to use the Gmail smart compose feature in my project. I read many documents but no documents suggest anything related to the implementation of smart compose in Gmail API.

Attaching a link below about the small information about the autocomplete feature:

[SmartCompose](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/suggestions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, this is not possible to do using the Gmail API.*

#### More information:

The Gmail API using the client libraries works on a request-response basis, and these are not retrievable through a Gmail API method. In order to do this, there would need to be a request made each time the string the user is typing changes, which would use not only require a lot of network traffic, but would also make application running slow as many requests would be made.

#### Feature Request:

On the flip side however, Google already knows about this, and a Feature Request for this has been made on their Issue Tracker. You can view this feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143089955), to which you can click the star (☆) in the top left to let Google know more people want this feature to be implemented.

#### References:

- [Autocomplete suggestions for text-inputs](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/suggestions)
- [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)
- [An API for gmail smart-compose feature](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143089955)